# How to enable the lift to Engineering in Executive?

Tags: system-shock, system-shock-2023

I'm in *Executive* trying to take the lift to *Engineering* but it is disabled and the PA says: "Elevator disabled. Biohazard emergency."

I already went to the three groves and disabled the interlocks, then activated the master control.

What else must I do and where is it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already activated the master control in Diego's suite, you have only one step remaining: Jettison the infected Beta Grove.

There is a large prominent lever on the wall of the grove control room right next to the Beta grove tram station. Pull it and enjoy the sight.